# Running similar analysis

Tags: scripts, sh

I have a folder with multiple sub-folders and files. They are all similar in name but the only difference is the patient's number

Example

```
Analysis/Patient_01/Brain/image_patient_01_merged.nii
Analysis/Patient_02/Brain/image_patient_02_merged.nii
Analysis/Patient_03/Brain/image_patient_03_merged.nii
.
.
.
```

and so on.

In the main folder (`Analysis`) I want to make a script to do the same thing for each `.nii` file in a loop.

example

```
fslstats image_patient_01_merged.nii -M
fslstats image_patient_02_merged.nii -M
fslstats image_patient_03_merged.nii -M
.
.
.
.
```

In other words, I need to do the same analysis on the nii files in each subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash, in the `Analysis` folder, use a simple for loop:

```
for f in */*/*.nii
do
    flstats "${f##*/}" -M
done
```

`*/*/*.nii` will expand to `Patient_01/Brain/image_patient_01_merged.nii`, etc., and `${f##*/}` gets just the filename `image_patient_01_merged.nii` from that.

Comment: Thanks, 
But each subdirectory has many .nii files for each patient

image_patient_01_merged.nii
crop_patient_01_original.nii
segmented_patient_01_new.nii
.
.
.
and so on. I only need to do the analysis for the 
image_patient_01_merged.nii file only in each patient directory and not to all .nii files

Comment: Is there a pattern to the nii filename?

Comment: Hi Muru,
I have added the details in the previous comment